# How to create Lucene index with NGramTokenizer with parameters in OrientDb?

Tags: lucene, orientdb

I'm looking for a way to use the [NGramTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html) in OrientDB. What I need is to pass the `minGram` and `maxGram` parameters to the constructor. [The documentation example](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Full-Text-Index.html) shows how to use analyzers with parameterless constructors:

```
orientdb> CREATE INDEX City.name ON City(name) FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE METADATA
          {"analyzer": "org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer"}
```

But how can one use the tokenizer with parameters? I could use something like this:

```
orientdb> CREATE INDEX City.name ON City(name) FULLTEXT ENGINE LUCENE METADATA
          {"analyzer": "org.apache.lucene.analysis.ngram.NGramTokenizer(2,3)"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `NGramTokenizer` is *not* an Analyzer, it's a Tokenizer.  You will need to pass in an [`Analyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html) as the analyzer argument.

You can write your own custom analyzer *using* `NGramTokenizer`, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17408195/1628375).

Comment: Thanks, this got you through 20k rep :)