# How to index documents that have the most common ngrams in their summaries using lucene

Tags: indexing, lucene, tokenize, n-gram

I have a set of articles and their corresponding summaries that have been generated using BART. These summaries, however, contain repetitions of ngrams. I need to index all the articles whose summaries contain these repetitions using Lucene.

I am new to java and to Lucene but I have been instructed to use it.

I came across [How to have ngram tokenizer in lucene 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407489/how-to-have-ngram-tokenizer-in-lucene-4-0) but I cannot understand t.o code the ngram tokenizer from the summaries, for my use case and then get the indices of the corresponding articles.

Please help!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question (and, apologies, I don't know what BART is). "_index all the articles whose summaries contain these repetitions_": (1) Are you saying you want to index a _subset_ of the available articles, based on what repeated ngrams they contain? Or (2) do you want to index everything? If it's a subset, then finding that subset is outside the scope of Lucene. If you want to index everything then what is stopping you? What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: Also (3) I don't know what you mean by "_These summaries, however, contain repetitions of ngrams_". I assume the summaries are just text. Do you want to capture specific ngrams in the Lucene indexed data? If so, which ones? That's not really how Lucene manages ngrams - broadly speaking, it generates all possible ngrams during indexing. Overall, it's unclear what you are asking, and what the specific issue is.

Comment: You can see a Lucene "getting started" demo, with code and overview, [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_10_1/demo/overview-summary.html#overview.description).